# `406 Not Acceptable` response: Error 406 - Not Acceptable

Tags: laravel-5.6, guzzle6

I uploaded laravel5.6 project on server and got this error. Running well on local machine.
when we request api using guzzle with laravel throwing error. Below is my code requesting api.

```
try{
 $response = $this->client->request('GET',$this->url.'index');
 $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
}catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            echo 'Caught response: '.$e;
}
```

returns 
Caught response: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET http://example.com/api/index` resulted in a `406 Not Acceptable` response:Error 406 - Not Acceptable

How to get solve this error

Comment: apache server and I hosted on inmotionhosting.com